# Using Java to Scan for Files and Filter them, basing on their Content (Backslicing)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, slice

I want to code a Program which will get a full Path to .Smali Files (Using APKtool on a .apk file already happened).

After that, you should have to Input a Function or Word. Then the Code should Scan all .smali files (like text files) and Scan for given function or Word. All .Smali which contain these should be saved in a new File and be printed to Console.

General Idea would be to Backslice for given Function or Word and find which .Smali files use these. (will be used to increase Security or find Security issues in App's)

I already tried (with help of some found code) to scan a Path for given .smali files. I now try to scan the files for a given Word (using a scanner). I only want the function to Print out and save .smali files which contains this Word.

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;


 
public class Final
{
    public void getFiles(String dir) throws IOException {
        File directory = new File(dir);
        //Verify if it is a valid file name
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Directory %s does not exist", dir));
            return;
        }
        //Verify if it is a directory and not a file path
        if (!directory.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Provided value %s is not a directory", dir));
            return;
        }
      //create a FileFilter and override its accept-method
        FileFilter logFilefilter = new FileFilter() {
                                       //Override accept method
                                       public boolean accept(File file) {
                                          //if the file extension is .smali return true, else false
                                          if (file.getName().endsWith(".smali")) {
                                             return true;
                                          }
                                          return false;
                                       }
                                    };
        
        File[] files = directory.listFiles(logFilefilter);

        // create an additional scanner to store the userInput (the word you want to find).
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the word that you want to find in the .smali files: ");
        String seekWord = userInput.nextLine(); //this line will store the line you are looking for
        userInput.close();

        // create an arrayList to store all the files that contain the word.
        List<File> filesWithWord = new ArrayList<>();

        //Let's list out the filtered files
        for (File f : files) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                // look in each line and if the line contains the word store the file.
                String word = sc.nextLine();
                if (word.contentEquals(seekWord)) {
                    System.out.println(f.getName());
                    filesWithWord.add(f);
                    continue; // no need to go through the rest of the lines.
                }

            }
            sc.close();
        }
        // create another file to store the results
        File fileWithFoundFiles = new File("C:\\examplePath\\results.txt");
        //make sure the parents of the file exist.
        fileWithFoundFiles.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        if (!fileWithFoundFiles.exists()) {
            fileWithFoundFiles.createNewFile();
        }
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fileWithFoundFiles)) { //try-with resources so your resource gets closed automatically
            for (File f : filesWithWord) {
                //write the fileNames to the file
                writer.write(f.getName() + "\n");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
       }
        
        
        
    }
    
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
       {
         Final Final = new Final();
         Final.getFiles("C:\\examplePath");
       }
}
```

Till now, the code just shows all Smali Files in the given path. I'm pretty bad at coding and don't know how to implement the filter for scanning all .smali files. (commented code in getFiles.class works fine on its own. but using a scanner, I am not able to store the file name which is scanned right now).

Maybe someone has an idea how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi in order to print all the files that contain the word you are seeking and writing them to a file you need to make a few changes in your `getFiles` method:

```
 public void getFiles(String dir) throws IOException {
        File directory = new File(dir);
        //Verify if it is a valid file name

        System.out.println("Looking for files in directory: " + dir);
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Directory %s does not exist", dir));
            return;
        }
        //Verify if it is a directory and not a file path
        if (!directory.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Provided value %s is not a directory", dir));
            return;
        }
        System.out.printf("files found in dir: %s%n", Arrays.asList(directory.listFiles()));
        //create a FileFilter and override its accept-method
        FileFilter logFilefilter = new FileFilter() {
            //Override accept method
            public boolean accept(File file) {
                //if the file extension is .smali return true, else false
                if (file.getName().endsWith(".smali")) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        };

        File[] files = directory.listFiles(logFilefilter);

        // create an additional scanner to store the userInput (the word you want to find).
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the word that you want to find in the .smali files: ");
        String seekWord = userInput.nextLine(); //this line will store the line you are looking for
        userInput.close();

        // create an arrayList to store all the files that contain the word.
        List<File> filesWithWord = new ArrayList<>();



        //Let's list out the filtered files
        for (File f : files) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                // look in each line and if the line contains the word store the file.
                String line = sc.nextLine();
                if (line.contains(seekWord)) {
                    System.out.println("found word " + seekWord + " in file: " + f.getName());
                    filesWithWord.add(f);
                    break; // no need to go through the rest of the lines.
                }

            }
            sc.close();
        }

        System.out.println("Smali files with the word: " + filesWithWord);
        // create another file to store the results
        File fileWithFoundFiles = new File("path/to/file/files.txt");
        //make sure the parents of the file exist.
        fileWithFoundFiles.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        if (!fileWithFoundFiles.exists()) {
            fileWithFoundFiles.createNewFile();
        }
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fileWithFoundFiles)) { //try-with resources so your resource gets closed automatically
            for (File f : filesWithWord) {
                //write the fileNames to the file
                System.out.println("writing file name " + f.getName() + " to " + f);
                writer.write(f.getName() + "\n");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }


    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195094/discussion-on-answer-by-stephan-hogenboom-using-java-to-scan-for-files-and-filte).